# Spring security 2.0.5. custom login form. Cannot see errors in language other than English

Tags: java, internationalization, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring

I've got my Spring Security custom login form working. It displays errors if the user has input bad credentials, or is expired, etc.

Looking inside spring-security-core-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar, I notice the following files in the org.springframework.security package:

messages.properties
messages_cs_CZ.properties
messages_de.properties
messages_fr.properties
...etc...

and notice that they have the localised versions of the strings.

Setting my browser's preferred language to French **doesn't make the French version of the string appear**. What am I missing?

PUK

Comment: Proably spring-security remembers you. Have you tried to clean up cookies/session?

Comment: This question has gone unanswered. Anybody know the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it:

In my applicationContext.xml I include the Spring Security messages by adding another basename:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>com.myapp.web.my_messages</value>
            <value>org.springframework.security.messages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In my web.xml I added another listener:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```